# ng-class 3 class types

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I liked the ternary operator but right now I've 3 values to deal with

```
<li class="table-view-cell media" ng-class="detail.keynote ? 'keynote' : 'session'">
```

javascript

```
detail.keynote = 0 //(class session)
detail.keynote = 1 //(class keynote)
deail.ketnote = -1 //(class neutral)
```

Any eloquent angular approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
       <li class="table-view-cell media" ng-class="{'session': detail.keynote==0,'keynote':detail.keynote==1,'neutral':detail.keynote==-1}" >
```

or

```
          <li class="table-view-cell media" ng-class="detail.keynote== 0 ? 'session' : (detail.keynote== 1 ? 'keynote' : 'neutral')">
```

Comment: i've some parsing errors, modified code but not working. `ng-class="'session': detail.keynote==0, 'keynote':detail.keynote==1, 'neutral':detail.keynote==-1"`

Comment: ng-class needs to be passed an object e.g { session: x == 1, keynote: x == 2 etc }

Comment: @Abdul Basit I'm getting errors with your code, please fix, I've a detail object with keynote as property